# mySQL how to change date format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

the date format in mySQL have type (yyyy-mm-dd), now I try to reverse it (dd-mm-yyyy).
I got table user

```
CREATE TABLE USER 
(
  USER_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DOB DATE,   
);
```

so when i insert value into that:

```
INSERT INTO USER(DOB) VALUES(DATE_FORMAT('13-07-1990','%d,%m,%Y));
```

however, it does not work. It notice that I should use 1990-07-13 instead of '13-07-1990'. 
please help me to do that. Thanks.

Comment: you can store it as text in varchar

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

Comment: This format is accepted as standard. It goes like `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-ii-ss`. As you can see starts with years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds, which is really easy to remember.

Comment: Is not possible to change the internal date format of mysql.

Comment: You cannot control internal representation of MySql date type. You can , however, format your query output any way you want.

Comment: I knew it, however, in my assignment, the requirement: dob has date type and input has format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', that's a point.

Answer (score 4):

The ANSI SQL standard format for date is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. It's easier to capture the date in this format for insertion into a database.

In order to store the date with the format you're using (`MM-DD-YYYY`) you need to use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function which allows you to convert a string to a date. The syntax for this function is:

> `STR_TO_DATE(str, format)`

The specifiers for the format can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

For your `INSERT` statement, you would use:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`dob`) VALUES
( STR_TO_DATE('13-07-1990','%d-%m-%Y') )
```

Comment: HI, when I used the query above, it appeared like this July, 13 1990 00:00:00+0000, I used %m instead of %M, why does it built like this? Please help me, thanks

Comment: @KucKu Are you trying to return this date somewhere?

Comment: sure, I test it on this link, take a look at this [SQL TEST](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3f2/12)

Comment: You can use `DATE_FORMAT` or `CONVERT`. [See a demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3f2/13)

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` is only used to save dates into varchar fields with non-standard formats or to retrieve them from the DB in a non-standard format. You may NOT save something in a `DATE` type field as any format besides **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Answer (score -1):

**FROM THE DOCS** : The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

My Way would be a little different.I would compute my date in php and pass the desired format to the query rather than computing it in query.

```
$your_date= "2010-03-21";
$desired_format = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($your_date));//returns 21-03-2010
$desired_format = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($your_date));//returns 03-21-2010
```

by using strtotime and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function,You can convert your date in to any format you desire

Comment: You can't assume that the OP is using server-side scripting.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO:he tagged php

Comment: My mistake. I would still have to argue that the date conversion on the application side is not only inefficient, the database functions are specifically designed to handle conversions.

Comment: i am googling about which is more efficient and less time consuming..let us see

Comment: Why not just test it yourself?